# session vs cache

Tags: session, caching

I just wanted to ask about the perofmrance difference between using cache or session...I know the difference between them but they are both MEMORY in server , but it's like session has access modifier "private" and cache has access modifier "public" so if they both take the same memory from server but the only difference is accessibility so what is the performance difference between session and cache?

Comment: Which language / framework / technology are you using?

Comment: Weird to state that you know the difference when your question is: whats the difference :D But well,theyre both totally different things :D Sessions are pretty easy to setup, and their ttl is clear: 1 session,whereas cache needs some more parameters and code and their ttl is not always clear. But Cache can be used for every1 on every moment, while Session cant. 
Guess you use ASP?

Comment: The terms `session` and `cache` are very widely used, so it's difficult to understand what do you actually mean when trying to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer from what I understand of your question.

Session is relative to a unique user (technically, a browser session). Session can hold for example, the name of the current logged in user. Session are identified by a SESSIONID, and request between the server and the browser references that ID. So, session is shared between the server and the browser. Server contains the data, browser contains the ID to access those data.

Cache is only used on the server, and is not related to a specific user. Also, cache is public, so every one could access to its data.

Comment: I know this difference very well....but session is saved on server memory and cache is saved on server memory....what is the PERFORMANCE difference between them....?

Comment: if i write cache["x"] and session["x"]....what is the performance difference whle they both on server and they both take from server memory...?? Note : I can add an id to every object set in cache so it becomes mostly like session..